# The hidden button will be shown just after entering the value text, without pressing any button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make something like that.
The hidden button will be shown just after entering the value text without pressing any button.

I mean, if someone types `Hazrat Shahjalal International Airport, Dhaka (DAC)`, the button will be visible. the below code works if I type the value in input, then run the code in browser's console.

I just started javaScript a few days ago. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
if (document.getElementById("fromAirport").value == "Hazrat Shahjalal International Airport, Dhaka (DAC)") {
        document.getElementById("SearchBtn").style.display = 'block';}
```

Comment: And there's the website that I forgot to mention https://creationtours-travels.com/  The form will appear after pressing "BOOK NOW" & the mentioned input field is the "From" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

```js
var inp = document.getElementById("fromAirport");
inp.addEventListener('input', function (){
if(inp.value === 'Hazrat Shahjalal International Airport, Dhaka (DAC)'){
   document.getElementById("SearchBtn").style.display = 'block';
}
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='fromAirport'>
<button id='SearchBtn' style='display:none;'>aaaa</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! You saved my day. I've also figured out that the plugin i was using wasn't working properly. Then I pasted your code inside <script> in Elementor and it worked as i wanted. Again thanks a lot :)